# How to generate "stellated" shapes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry, procedural

I'm talking about shapes like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

I've installed "Extra Object" add-on, but I still don't know whether it can generate this kind of shape and where the option is.

Comment: You could just borrow a couple of steps from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229959/35559). (Make a regular solid, get rid of unwanted edges, poke, scale. Or GZ with 'Normal' orientation.)

Comment: @RobinBetts what does 'GZ' stand for here?

Comment: That's the literal keyboard shortcut for 'grab(move) & constrain to the Z axis'. Here used  with face-center vertices selected. (Pivot: 'Individual Origins', Orientation: 'Normal' in the header dropdowns)

Comment: @RobinBetts ... dammit ... I didnt notice your comment ... grrr

Comment: @vklidu np :D .. different angle on it, and no add-ons.

Comment: @RobinBetts ... cosmetics ... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Add *Icosphere > Subdivision 1*

[image]

- *Bevel Vertices* <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> type <kbd>0.304</kbd>, *Merge by distanc* <kbd>M</kbd>

[image]

- Search *Poke Faces*

[image]

- Scale <kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Solution with geometry nodes:

1. add an icosphere with 1 subdivision

[image]

2. hide the icosphere and add a Mesh -> Circle with 5 vertices

[image]

3. Go in edit-mode, E to extrude, Z and move up

[image]

4. Press M to merge vertices -> at center

[image]

5. Go to object mode and hide this "circle" and unhide the icosphere and create this geometry node setup for the icosphere:

[image]

result:

[image]

Depending on your dimensions it might be necessary that you change the threshold value a bit.